# Unexpected end of .bashrc file

Tags: boot, drivers, sound, pulseaudio, startup

I was having issues with pulseaudio and had to every time type in 'pulseaudio -D' in terminal each time I booted up. However, this was quite frustrating and so I was looking forward to make pulseaudio to startup each time at bootup by editing .bashrc

I added these lines at the end of the .bashrc file :

```bsh
until [[ `ps aux | grep "pulseaudio -D" | grep -v grep | wc -l` -eq 1 ]]
do
    pulseaudio -D >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [[ `ps aux | grep "pulseaudio -D" | grep -v grep | wc -l` -gt 1 ]]
    then
        kill -9 `pidof pulseaudio`
        pulseaudio -D
    fi
```

https://pastebin.com/QC6LV50d

But since after that I have been getting the error of 'unexpected end of file' as enclosed in the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd8bj.jpg).

How can I solve it?

Comment: All you're missing is the `done` after `fi` to close the `do` loop.

Comment: After adding done to it, each time I open a new terminal, I have to do ctrl+C to continue using the terminal. It's like as if a process is already running after adding the 'done' word in the end

Comment: Technically Kali is not supported here.  So, this should be asked at https://unix.stackexchange.com/  Secondly, Kali was never intended to be installed as an everyday OS.  See https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux  That being said, The .bashrc is loaded every single time you launch a terminal window.  This would be best to be dropped into a script that is called at start up and possibly put into a CRON job to run every so often.

Comment: And now it aint about Kali anymore :)

Answer (score 4):

Your `do` loop lacks ending with `done`. [Compare](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for i in *; do
    echo "item: $i"
done
```

Comment: FYI I changed `for i in $( ls )` because of [Bash Pitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) - I suggest you find a more reliable programming guide than the one you linked.

Comment: I'm OK with it, it was first I found and I don't do much bash scripting so any tips on good practice is welcome.

Comment: After adding done to it, each time I open a new terminal, I have to do ctrl+C to continue using the terminal. It's like as if a process is already running after adding the 'done' word in the end

Comment: @gonczor [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)